# jquery mobile dialog close going back too in history

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have javascript open a dialog (which is just some text, nothing else) on any/every page someone lands on my site (yes, I know it's a mixture of javascript flavors - still getting to grips with this):

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    if( getCookieValue('instructionseen') == false)
        {
        $.mobile.changePage("/php/instructions_alert.php");
        document.cookie ="instructionseen=yes; path=/;";
        }
    });
```

The script sets a cookie so that the user only sees the dialog once. So the idea is you come to the site, get a dialog with some instrctions, close it and carry on.

The problem in Chrome v24 (and I'm worried it might occur in mobile browsers that I cannot test on) is that closing the dialog brings me back 2 pages in the history, so I get back to the page with the link I clicked on to get to my site.

For example, say my site is MS, and is it linked to by RS (referrer site)

```
Desired: RS > click to MS > Dialog opens > close it > MS in view

On Chrome: RS > click to MS > Dialog opens > close it > back to RS
```

This happens using the X provided by JQM, or this close botton I provide:

```
<a href='#' onclick='$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");' data-role='button' data-theme='c'>Close</a>
```

Dialog source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<title>title..</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/design/mobile_style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css' />
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/main_and_JQM_init.min.js'></script> 
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role='dialog'  id='instructions_alert_div' data-overlay-theme='b'>
        <div data-role='header' data-theme='d'>
            <h1>Important!</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role='content' data-theme='c'>
        content, just text...
        <a href='#' onclick='$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");' data-role='button' data-theme='c'>Close</a>

        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Forgot to say, this is JQM 1.2 final

Comment: Can you post the markup of your dialog?

Comment: @Omar - dialog posted. You helped me with a similar problem a week or 2 ago, am not having much luck with dialogs!

Comment: I'm working on an alternative, to use a popup instead of dialog, so far it's looking promising - just in case someone spends time on this.

Comment: It goes back to "R5" page because the dialog was generated by that page. It should be generated by "MS" page. Therefore, try this. `$("#MS").bind("pageinit", function()` and in the dialog `data-rel="back"`. it should go back to "MS" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

**Markup:**

```
 <!-- Start of first page -->

 <div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page1 header</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>page 1</p>

    <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Page 2</a>


</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page1 Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


 <!-- Start of second page -->

 <div data-role="page" id="page2">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>password accepted</p>        
    <p><a href="#test" data-rel="dialog">dialog</a></p>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page2 Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
 </div><!-- /page -->
```

**Dialog:**

```
 <div data-role='dialog'  id='test' data-overlay-theme='b'>
    <div data-role='header' data-theme='d'>
        <h1>Important!</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role='content' data-theme='c'>
    content, just text...
      <a href='#' onclick='$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");' data-role='button' data-theme='c'>Close</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JQM:**

```
$("#page2").on('pageinit', function(event) {
$.mobile.changePage($("#test"), {
    transition : 'pop',
    reverse    : true,
    changeHash : true
});
 });
```

JSfiddle: [dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/C7E3E/1/)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that. Further to your last comment, page RS is NOT on my site, it is a link to my site from a third party. But your code is useful form a learning point of view.

Comment: Oh I see..but does it solve your problem? If not, I will amend it. Pls let me know.

Comment: Hi, well I've gone and used a popup instead - I posted that in comments I was looking at that before you posted that solution. My client actually much preferred it to the dialog when he saw it. The popup is working well on PC, Andriod and Iphone